# Powershell Restore-SQLDatabase not working when all inputs are correct

Tags: sql-server, database, powershell

I am attempting to automate the process of restoring certain Databases. I am pulling the .bak files from a repo and writing a PS script to restore each one. My code looks like:

```
Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance "(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB" -Database "Acct" -BackupFile "C:\myFile.bak"
```

While these inputs would work in a normal SQL Management Studio, I get the error:

```
Restore-SqlDatabase : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Directory lookup for the file 

"D:\Data\Databases\SQL2008\myFile.mdf" 

failed with the operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).

+ Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance "(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB" -Databas ...

+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Restore-SqlDatabase], SmoException

+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionFailed,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.RestoreSqlDatabaseCommand
```

I get confused because I dont have anything on the D drive and its looking for stuff in there despite not being referenced anywhere. I am also just overall confused on what I am doing wrong despite following the docs to a T.

All my SQL Servers are up and running.

Comment: That path comes from the bak file where it backed up from. You might consider using -ReplaceDatabase param if it is a new database image.

Comment: -ReplaceDatabase wasn't what I was looking for but your advice made me realize that the reason it was going into that path was because that is where it was trying to place the mdf. Therefore, adding the -AutoRelocate parameter fixed it. Thanks.